# Texpad OS X, how do you add a new shortcut to typeset?

Tags: compiling, texpad, code-snippets

I want to add another shortcut to compile a document in [Texpad](https://www.texpad.com).

The default one is `cmd + T`, while I'd like to create another one with `cmd + enter` (enter key).

[Here](https://www.texpad.com/support/osx/editor/snippets) you can find a short guide about snippet on Texpad for OS X.

A sample code used to create a bold text is

```
% Snippet to make text bold
% Insert a \textbf command, or surround any selected text with \textbf
ctrl key = b
group = Inline
insert at cursor = \textbf{<SELECTION>}
```

I can simply change the `b` with `enter`, but I don't know how to make the command running the whole document just written.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not what snippets are meant for:

> Since version 1.5, Texpad has supported Snippets functionality to make it easy to **insert regularly used blocks of text into your document**.

[Build scripts](https://www.texpad.com/support/osx/typesetting/custom-typesetting), on the other hand, let you define custom build sequences but as far as I know there's no way to set a different shortcut to each of them (you usually select a script from the `Typeset` menu and keep using `cmd+T` to build the project).

A workaround is replacing `cmd+T` by `cmd+enter` (I know it isn't exactly what you asked for):

[image]

- head to ` > System Preferences > Keyboard`;
- go to the `Shortcuts` tab;
- select `App Shortcuts` in the left hand side menu;
- click on the `+` sign;
- select `Texpad.app` from the `Application` dropdown menu;
- fill in `Menu Title` with `Typeset`;
- click on the `Keyboard Shortcut` box and press `cmd+enter`on your keyboard;
- click on `Add`.

Once you're done `cmd+enter` will have replaced `cmd+T` in Texpad:

[image]

[Support page on on apple.com](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25377?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

Comment: It works! Thank you. Only one addition to your post: the name given to the "Menu Title" should be given in the language set on Texpad, i.e. mine is in Italian, hence I've used "Compila" instead of "Typeset".

Answer (score 0):

You can use TextEdit to write the changes you want to the snippet, name it whatever you want and save as .snippet in the snippets folder TexPad already has. You then need to quit TexPad and open it again for the snippet to be loaded. enter will not work as a choice I do not know if it is recognized as return or Enter but I think it needs to just be the letters, symbols or numbers on the keyboard. Even if you use a key such as Tab or enter, your snippet will work but you need to access it from the snippets menu then since the keyboard shortcut won't work.

Also, since it is to compile the code you will likely need to change the type into Environment since you are not placing anything inline.

Hope this helps.