# Can I create custom templates in Texpad for iOS?

Tags: templates, texpad

I would like to create custom templates in Texpad for iOS. The 7 pre-set templates are extremely skimpy—they don’t actually have enough code in them for a document to generate when text is added between the \begin{document} and \end{document} lines!

There doesn’t seem to be an obvious way to add custom templates, and the extensive guides and FAQs in the settings page make no mention of it.

Comment: This type of question is best answered by texpad help desk from your account however from the guidance ~~ if you open a file in your Dropbox app on iOS, you see an Export button, ios-export-button in the bottom left corner, ~~ Files imported in this way will be copied to the Texpad-Imported-Files folder in the root of your local iOS storage. THUS if you start with mytmplt## **#.tex** file In your dropbox and export / import it  then you have a copy to work with ensure you don't overwrite your templates. If this does not work for you see my first suggestion

Comment: You may have to built a custom typesetting build script see here https://www.texpad.com/support/osx/typesetting/custom-typesetting however I do not use iOS so will need to see if others can confirm and there are .tpbuild examples and other snippets here https://github.com/vallettaventures/TexpadKB other related info at https://github.com/aneitel/texpadSnippets https://github.com/moritzfl/texpad-academic-md  https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Mac_Installation#Texpad and hints here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344429/texpad-os-x-how-do-you-add-a-new-shortcut-to-typeset

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can create a custom template.

```
File -> Add/Edit Templates
```

There, you can find existing templates and choose to add a new one. See [documentation on File](https://www.texpad.com/docs/apps/workspace/menu-items) for more details.

P.S. I was searching for the same issue and found this solution. Although the question is three years old, with 600+ views I'm sure it will help someone for sure.